# Cannot get value from database-bound dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I'm using asp.net 4.5 web forms with VS2017 and using dropdownlist to get the values
from the database and try to get the value but it keeps giving me only the top value, so I'm asking for help.

The way I binded the value is this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new dbContext();
    var CustItem = db.customer.ToList();

    customerDropDownList.DataSource = CustItem;
    customerDropDownList.DataTextField = "cust";
    customerDropDownList.DataValueField = "cust";
    customerDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

and it works nicely and gets all the list in customer table and populates the data in cust column in the id : customerDropDownList.
And then I tried to get the value from customerDropDownList by having a testBtn
with testLbl attached and used

```
protected void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testLbl.Text = customerDropDownList.SelectedValue;
}
```

and it only selects the top element always.

I suspect this has to do with the lifecycle of asp.net and am studying about it
but cannot find the clear answer to solve this.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Wrap your data binding code in " if not postback" block

Comment: @mjwills the original is a lot more complicated than this. I'm using the minimal and essential code to make people read easily. I could provide examples also but I figured it was unnecessary. I am gonna provide the frontend code for clarity.

Comment: @Crowcoder omg.. it works.. I wanna kill myself..

Comment: @Crowcoder you should make it an answer so I can select yours

Comment: That is a very common mistake answered a hundred times already so no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `Page.IsPostBack` in page load event

more on Ispostback [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

With your code are you not noticing your dropdown list is doubled on the click ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var db = new dbContext();
        var CustItem = db.customer.ToList();

        customerDropDownList.DataSource = CustItem;
        customerDropDownList.DataTextField = "cust";
        customerDropDownList.DataValueField = "cust";
        customerDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Make sure to load the dropdown only once. your page load will be called on the button click as well.

Keep a break point and play around !! Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you are resetting the dropdown list on each page load. Try only setting the ddlist the first time.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var db = new dbContext();
        var CustItem = db.customer.ToList();

        customerDropDownList.DataSource = CustItem;
        customerDropDownList.DataTextField = "cust";
        customerDropDownList.DataValueField = "cust";
        customerDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
}
```